# digestive-functors to parse multiple inputs with the same name

Tags: haskell, digestive-functors

I'm trying to use digestive-functors to parse a form with a variable number of dynamically generated inputs, something like this:

```
<form>
  <input type="hidden" name="object-id" value="123">
  <input type="hidden" name="object-id" value="43">
  <input type="hidden" name="object-id" value="467">
</form>
```

But am unsure on how to do this. I see there's a `listOf` function, but it looks like it requires the input names to have an index in them and be created all at once, which I don't want, since these inputs are being populated dynamically.

The haskell type is something like:

```
data Form = Form { objectIds :: [Int] }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean parse a form? It's not clear what is being asked.